# Hamster in an aeroplane who can talk - NOT 'Tales From the Riverbank'

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I'm trying to remember a book I read as a kid (I'm early 50's so it would have been in the late 1970's when I read it). It's about a boy who gets a pet hamster and decides to put it in his toy airplane and fly it around his room. The hamster is scared and knows it needs to somehow tell the boy how much he hates it, so when the plane lands and the boy takes him out. The hamster speaks but the speech is written very phonetically, such as: 'Meee no leek eet'..... can't remember much of the rest apart from the hamster becoming famous. Does anyone know what the book is?